# Why magento uses global attribute for configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, scope

As we all know that Magento requires global scope attribute for creating a configurable product.

But my question is why its needed so?

Why can't we create a configurable product with an attribute with store scope?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/magento-1.9.3.3/info

check now please

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, Can you help me with this ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221049/magento-2-notice-error-array-to-string-conversion
I need some suggestions or guide.