# Magento 2 : Notice Error - Array to String conversion

Tags: database, uicomponent, plugin, magento2.2.3

I've been trying to save **Multi Select** field values to DB.

> I've added the field to sales rule form using ui_component.

```
<fieldset name="exclude_brands">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Exclude Brands</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="start_date" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Start Date</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <dataScope>start_date</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="end_date" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>

            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">End Date</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <dataScope>end_date</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="brand_ids" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-brands" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>varchar</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Brand List</label>
            <dataScope>brand_ids</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Block\SalesRule\BrandList"/>

                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

To save this field I've created a plugin with **after execute** method.

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save">
    <plugin name="save_brands" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\brands" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

> Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Brands.php

```
public function afterexecute(\Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save $save,$result)
{

    $ruleId =  $save->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id'); 

    $brandIds = implode(',',$save->getRequest()->getParam('brand_ids'));

    try{
        $salesRuleData =  $this->salesRule->load($ruleId);
        $salesRuleData->setStartDate($save->getRequest()->getParam('start_date'));
        $salesRuleData->setEndDate($save->getRequest()->getParam('end_date'));
        $salesRuleData->setBrandIds($brandIds);
        $salesRuleData->save();         
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }

}
```

Now, issue is **field value is saving to DB**  but, Getting exception like below.

> Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.

Check Below Error Log.

```
(Exception(code: 0): Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mage2\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Statement\\Pdo.php on line 228 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mage2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Anyone facing same issues before. Really need help with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `$salesRuleData->setBrandIds($brandIds);` check for $brandids data type. they are in array or string

Comment: @Rizwan, It returns array,  So i converted into string and than set it to its object.

Comment: Please comment this line $salesRuleData->setBrandIds($brandIds); 
and check that after comment this line still exception is generated while saving to DB ?.

Comment: Yes, I did that, Same Exception while save if i select value from multiselect.

Comment: If after comment above line still you are getting same exception then there is no error in your ui_component code.Please check your plugin.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd., Plugin code is same as above. What's wrong in it !!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't know why plugin doesn't work with current scenario.**

If anyone tell Why plugin not worked with this scenario ?

So, I used event called `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` to save my fields value to **DB**.

Here is full code.

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<event name="adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save">
    <observer name="save_brands" 
        instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SaveExcludedBrands" />
</event>
```

Than, Create observer file within your module.

> Vendor/Module/Observer/SaveExcludedBrands.php

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $data = $observer->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    //print_r($data); exit;
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();

    $brands = implode(',',$data['brands']);

    $startDate = $this->timeZoneInterface->date($data['start_date'])->format('Y-m-d'); 
    $endDate = $this->timeZoneInterface->date($data['end_date'])->format('Y-m-d');


    $request->setPostValue('brands',$brands);
    $request->setPostValue('start_date',$startDate);
    $request->setPostValue('end_date',$endDate);
}
```

Now, No exception and notice and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
public function afterexecute(\Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save $save,$result)
{

    $ruleId =  $save->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id'); 

  $brandIds = implode(',',$save->getRequest()->getParam('brands'));

    try{
        $salesRuleData =  $this->salesRule->load($ruleId);
        $salesRuleData->setStartDate($save->getRequest()->getParam('start_date'));
        $salesRuleData->setEndDate($save->getRequest()->getParam('end_date'));
        $salesRuleData->setBrands($brandIds);
        $salesRuleData->save();         
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }

}
```

Comment: I've already tried your way before but same **Notice Error**.

Comment: What column type use in table

Comment: If you use single brand id.

Comment: Same issue, Values saving to table but notice error there.

Comment: If use 
`$salesRuleData->setBrands(4);` , Means if i set static value than its working but when dynamic values come than it started throwing notice error.

Dyamic it returns array , I did try both way directly set array OR by implode it But both not working.

Also used `$salesRuleData->setData('brands',$brands);
 $salesRuleData->updateData($salesRuleData);` way to set brands but no luck

Comment: Not issue in dynamic code. Issue when brand ids save in this format (4,5,21)

Comment: Yes correct, I've multiselect and it's going to store values like 224,223,225 something like this.

Comment: can you send me output of this 
$data = $save->getRequest()->getPost();
print_r($data);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75818/discussion-between-lazy-coder-and-sourav).

Comment: Post data is too long to post here, It's out of limit of area. Please check in chat i posted array.

Comment: I think solved.