# Magento 2 : ui_component and its values

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent

I know most of been gone through the Magento 2's **ui_component**.

I would like to know that If i add new field in existing ui_component of core code,

> Do i need to write my custom code to save my field's value to db ?

Any one has idea about it ??

Thanks.

Comment: For more details, Can you upload your file code?

Comment: Check here, [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221049/magento-2-notice-error-array-to-string-conversion) ,
 If you can !!

Answer (score 0):

**=> For example :**

you have made some changes in product's ui forms, then for that you need to keep **form element name** same as **database_column name**.

Then, You don't need to do any save process.

But, If you add a column in a custom database then you need to do code for save in product save after observer event.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I've added text field and its saving its value to DB No issues, Now if i add multiselect and add new field to DB with same name does it work ? without any custom code ?!